# How do I find out the last-modified time of a Maven artifact?

Tags: maven, aether

Each artifact uploaded to Maven Central has a `last modified` time associated with it. You can see an example of this by drilling into an artifact's details on [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.inject%7Cguice%7C3.0%7Cjar).

**How do I retrieve an artifact's `last modified` time using Aether?**

I am retrieving this information purely for human consumption (i.e. "How long ago did this project make a release? Is it being actively maintained?").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to retrieve this information (though not officially supported) is to [construct the Artifact's URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068745/14731) and issue an `HTTP HEAD` to retrieve the `Last-Modified` header.

I'm not aware of any official API to do this (suggestions welcome!)

Comment: This is not consistent with the actual release date of an artifact. For `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:1.0-alpha-4`, `Last-Modified` is in 2020, while the JAR itself was released back in 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend constructing the artifact's URL, parsing the directory listing and extracting the datetime string. Here's a simple POC in Python:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_publication_date_from_maven_repo(group_id, artifact_id, version):
    group_id = group_id.replace(".", "/")

    url = f"https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/{group_id}/{artifact_id}/{version}"

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        pom_link = soup.find("a", href=f"{artifact_id}-{version}.pom")

        if pom_link:
            date_text = jar_link.parent.text.split()[-3]
            publication_date = datetime.strptime(date_text, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime(
                "%Y-%m-%d"
            )
            return publication_date
        else:
            print(f"Could not find POM link for {group_id}:{artifact_id}:{version}")
            return None

    except requests.HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f"HTTP error occurred: {http_err}")
        return None
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Other error occurred: {err}")
        return None
```

Please not that this works only for the Maven Central Repository, and you would have to change the URL to support other repositories.