# How do I find out an artifact's URI?

Tags: maven, aether

How do I use the [Aether library](http://eclipse.org/aether/) to look up an artifact's URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aether-users/msg00127.html, you can do the following:

```
Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact("com.google.guava", "guava", "jar", "18.0");
MavenDefaultLayout defaultLayout = new MavenDefaultLayout();
RemoteRepository centralRepository = new RemoteRepository.Builder("central", "default", "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/").build();
URI centralUri = URI.create(centralRepository.getUrl());
URI artifactUri = centralUri.resolve(defaultLayout.getPath(artifact));
```

Where `artifact` should be changed to the artifact you want to look up.

Answer (score 0):

just to complete the correct answer.
you can create an artifact like this

```
Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact("com.google.guava", "guava", "jar", "18.0");
```