# Retrieving artifact release date using Aether Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, aether

I am new to the Aether eclipse plugin, and I am wondering if there is a way (or a XXXRequest) that is able to retrieve the release date of a Maven artifact?

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Cheers,

Comment: Can you give more details about `Aether eclipse plugin`? Cause I don't know of any? Furthermore can you elaborate more in detail what you like to achieve?

Comment: I've edited an answer to my question. Here is a quick pointer to the Aether-Eclipse plugin (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/What_Is_Aether).
Thanks for your help. Next time I'll try to ask elaborated and precise questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, it appeared that using Aether-Eclipse plugin API does not enable accessing the artifact release date. I've found a nice workaround in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068600/how-do-i-find-out-the-last-modified-time-of-a-maven-artifact).